# menu en la parte derecha

Tags: reactjs, ccs, react-bootstrap

Hola tengo un componete en React boostrap de un NavBar, funciona bien lo único es que al desplegar me muestra el menú en la parte derecha (como lo muestra la figura) [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]y quisiera ver la posibilidad de mostrarlo en la parte izquierda, aca el codigo:

```
import { Button,Nav,  Navbar, Container, FormControl, Form, Offcanvas, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import '../index.css'

 const NavBar=() =>{
    return (

        <Navbar bg="light" expand={false}>
        <Container fluid>
        <div >
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" />
            </div>
            <Navbar.Brand className="navbar-brand-custom"  href="#">hola</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Offcanvas
            id="offcanvasNavbar"
            aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
            placement="end"
          >
            <Offcanvas.Header closeButton>
              <Offcanvas.Title id="offcanvasNavbarLabel">Offcanvas</Offcanvas.Title>
            </Offcanvas.Header>
            <Offcanvas.Body>
              <Nav className="justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <Nav.Link href="#action1">Home</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link href="#action2">Link</Nav.Link>
               
              </Nav>

            </Offcanvas.Body>
            </Navbar.Offcanvas>

        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: No muestras mucho el CSS. ¿y si borras ese <div class='text-right'>?

Comment: no tengo nada en el css trabajo con React boostrap, ese div me posiciona el boton del menu en la parte derecha pero lo que necesito es que el slice del menu salga de la parte derecha y no de la izquierda

Comment: Incluye el componente donde se llama a Navbar, probablemente eso nos de más pistas

Comment: es el único componente que tengo en el ReactDOM.render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta cambiar esta parte

```
<Navbar.Offcanvas
      id="offcanvasNavbar"
      aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
      placement="end"
    >
```

por esto

```
<Navbar.Offcanvas
      id="offcanvasNavbar"
      aria-labelledby="offcanvasNavbarLabel"
      placement="start"
    >
```

Eso debería modificar la clase `offcanvas-end` por `offcanvas-start` que en CSS te lleva todo a la izquierda

Comment: hermano eres un genio, muchas gracias funciono prfecto